# Does every random variable induces a probability measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am learning probabilistic measure theory. I have a doubt. Can anyone please help me.

Let us a consider a random variable defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathbb{F},P)$ and taking values $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B})$.

Then how can I show that this random variable induces a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B})$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) out

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X : (\Omega,\mathbb{F},P) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B})$ is your random variable, then
$$\mu(A) = P\left(\omega\in\Omega \colon X(\omega)\in A\right),\quad A\in\mathbb{B}$$

$\mu$ is a probabilty measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B})$, sinse $\mu(A)\ge 0$ as the initial probabilty $P$ is non-negative, and countable aditivity:
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_n A_n\right) = P\left(\omega\in\Omega \colon X(\omega)\in \bigcup_n A_n\right) = \sum_n P\left(\omega\in\Omega \colon X(\omega)\in A_n\right) = \sum_n \mu(A_n)$$

Comment: Could you please explain why this true $P\left(\omega\in\Omega \colon X(\omega)\in \bigcup_n A_n\right) = \sum_n P\left(\omega\in\Omega \colon X(\omega)\in A_n\right)$.

Comment: If $A\cap B = \varnothing$ then $\{\omega\in\Omega \colon X(\omega)\in A\cup B\} = \{\omega\in\Omega \colon X(\omega)\in A\}\cup\{\omega\in\Omega \colon X(\omega)\in B\}$. This is true because $X(\omega)\in A\cup B \iff X(\omega)\in A \text{ or } X(\omega)\in B$, and it can't be a case $X(\omega)\in A$ and $X(\omega)\in B$, sinse $A\cap B = \varnothing$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.